# How to allow one period only in Datagridview Cell in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell, keypress

I am trying to make my datagridview cell to accept numbers only and a single period.

so far I have successfully made it to accept numbers only, here is the code:

```
    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ".", vbBack
            e.Handled = False
        Case Else
            e.Handled = True
    End Select
```

In my textbox, I will also accept numbers and single period only, here is the code:

```
    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ".", vbBack
            e.Handled = False
        Case Else
            e.Handled = True
    End Select


    If (txt1.Text.IndexOf(".") >= 0 And e.KeyChar = ".") Then e.Handled = True
```

All of the code are in KeyPress event.
I have no idea how to make my datagridview cell accept single period only.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: That last line in your second code block should do it.  Do you have other code after this that might set Handled back to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event dealing better with what you want is `CellValueChanged`: it will just check the definitive value and, eventually, correct it. Also you can rely on `IsNumeric` to quickly find valid numbers. Sample code for `DataGridView1`:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

    If (e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0) Then

        Dim curVal As String = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
        If (curVal.Trim().Length > 0) Then

            If (curVal.Contains(".")) Then
                'Checking whether the given entry has more tha one period

                Dim temp() As String = curVal.Split("."c)
                If (temp.Length > 2) Then
                  'More than one period
                   DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = temp(0) & "." & temp(1)
                ElseIf (Not IsNumeric(curVal)) Then
                   'Is not numeric
                   DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = ""
                End If

            ElseIf (Not IsNumeric(curVal)) Then
                'Any other non-numeric entry
                DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = ""
            End If

       End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Bear in mind that `IsNumeric` will catch any non-numeric situation (for example: 1.32.52), thus I have included a pre-condition to check specific cases with more than one period to show you how you can deal with different situations (you might analyse the whole string to remove specific parts, instead just deleting the whole cell).

Comment: @varcobas: Hi sir, thanks for the answer, from this code I have made a working code now. Big help for me, thank you again :)

Comment: oops sorry about that

Comment: @Matthew No problem. I take it personally only with Spanish-speaking people ;)

Answer (score 0):

IT IS VERY SIMPLE TO RESTRICT DUPLICATE PERIOD BUTTON IN DATAGRID VIEW YOU JUST SUPPLY BEWLOW MENTIONED CODE IN EditingControlShowingEventArgs EVENT AND CREATE A PRIVATE SUB FOR CONTROL_PRESS EVENT.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)

        RemoveHandler tb.KeyPress, AddressOf CONTROL_KEYPRESS
        If Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Or Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
            AddHandler tb.KeyPress, AddressOf CONTROL_KEYPRESS
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CONTROL_KEYPRESS(ByVal SENDER As TextBox, ByVal E As KeyPressEventArgs)

    If (Not Char.IsControl(E.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsDigit(E.KeyChar) And E.KeyChar <> "."c) Then
        E.Handled = True
    End If
    If (E.KeyChar = "."c And SENDER.Text.IndexOf("."c) > -1) Then
        E.Handled = True

    End If

End Sub
```

PREPED BY FURQAN HALEEM